# I want the button in annotation to always appear

Tags: swift, uikit, mapkit, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

The application I developed creates an annotation on the map when pressed and held. When this annotation is touched, the button and other information appear. But I want the button and other information to appear directly (without touching it). And I don't know that how to use the button.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class choosingVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChooseLocation(gestureRecognizer:)))
        gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc func ChooseLocation(gestureRecognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
            let touchCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = touchCoordinate
            annotation.title = "seçitiğiniz bölge"
            annotation.subtitle = "örnek"
            
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

//annotation artı butonu ekledik.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if !(annotation is MKUserLocation) {
               let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: String(annotation.hash))

               let rightButton = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
               rightButton.tag = annotation.hash

               pinView.animatesDrop = true
               pinView.canShowCallout = true
               pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton

               return pinView
           }
           else {
               return nil
           }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe setting `isSelected = true` on `pinView` will help.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply, when I write this code   """ mapview.isSelected = true  """ . Simulator only showed button part.Not shown information text